# How to get the text in a label to blink?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get the text in a label to blink.This is the code that I am using:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<script src="../jquery-1.3.2.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="../jquery-blink.js" language="javscript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('.blink').blink();        
});

</script>
<div runat="server" id="blinkText">                    
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">
</asp:Label>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

In code behind:

```
lblMessage.Text = "You can not complete the test unless you solve all the questions";
blinkText.Attributes.Add("class", "blink");
```

The message appears at run time but it does not blink.Where have I gone wrong?Another information which might be useful is that this label lblMessage is inside an Update Panel.

Comment: Is the plugin being added as expected?

Answer (score 1):

your label id is `lblMessage` and you can add your class to it instead of  `blinkText`
your code is :

```
lblMessage.Text = "You can not complete the test unless you solve all the questions";
blinkText.Attributes.Add("class", "blink");
```

change it as :

```
lblMessage.Text = "You can not complete the test unless you solve all the questions";
lblMessage.Attributes.Add("class", "blink");
```

and try ...

Comment: @Farrokh , I have tried this but this hasn't worked.

Comment: blink is deprecated, use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are doing a Class selector there `$('.blink')`
So for that to work, you need to add that class to the Label

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="blink" ForeColor="Red">
</asp:Label>
```

or what I would prefer is the normal Element selector via ID

```
$('<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').blink();
```

When using MasterPages with `ContentPlaceHolders` you just add your contentplace holder ID before the element ID in the selector with underscore like so

```
$('ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMessage').blink();
```

//Just debug this, now and then it adds other characters like `$ct01_` infront of the contentplaceholder part `$('$ct01_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMessage')`

***Edit***

If you want to make the whole `Div` Blink,
use the following javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#blinkText').blink();        
});
```

else if you only want the elements to blink which has the `blink` class assigned to them, then assign the classes correctly as @Farrokh has mentioned in his answer

Comment: Well, you could also probably make the whole `Div` blink :)

Comment: I believe that is what the OP is trying but failing to achieve, hence the question.

Comment: @Pierre This is not working for me.I have tried out almost all of the suggestions given to me.

Comment: @TVicky try this line of code server-side `lblMessage.CssClass = "blink";` with your code as you have had it before doing this post. Should work for you :)

Comment: @TVicky also change your javascript to this `$(function(){ $('.blink').blink(); });`. Then last but not least, remove the `<script src="../jquery-1.3.2.min ....` and add the latest version of jquery `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Its not required, Its just better

Answer (score 0):

Using System.Threading, add an AJAX timer control and a ScriptManager to your aspx page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:timer runat="server" ID="tmr1" Interval="300000" ontick="tmr1_Tick"></asp:timer>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

in timer_tick event put the following codes:

```
protected void tmr1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            lblMessage.Visible = false;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK dude,if your problem not solved yet try this:

1. place a `span` in your `HTML` and add `class='blink'` to it, then reload page to see what happened.
2. there are two result:

   1. `span` was blinked, then your server side code had problem, we should to check it
   2. `span` not blinked, then your client side code had problem and we should to correct it.

We're waiting for your answer ...

Comment: OK, your problem is client side, change your jQuery library version and retry

Comment: and put your script inside your `head` atg or before `body` end tag, it will help you